# Scala match on Option[Object] not exhaustive with Some(o) and None in Akka receive function

Tags: multithreading, scala, jvm, akka, actor

For the match on *Option[Entity]* below, a third case is required to be exhaustive. Why ?

*entitiesMap* is a *var* containing an immutable *Map[UUID,Entity]*. It is accessed and updated within a single Akka Actor to avoid threading issues. Here is an excerpt of the *receive* function:

```
class WorldActor extends Actor {

  var world: World = null

  override def receive = {

    case WorldSet(w) =>
      world = w

    // get that state and apply it to its entity
    case s: State if (world != null) =>
      val uuid = new UUID(s.getUuid().getL1(), s.getUuid().getL2())
      world.entitiesMap.get(uuid) match {
        case Some(ent) =>
          // Update entity's state
          ent.setEntityState(s)
        case None =>
          Log.error("World doesn't contain entity uuid: " + uuid)
        case other =>
          Log.error("Received unknown message: " + other)
      }

    case AddEntity(ent) if (world != null && ent != null) =>
      if (!world.entitiesMap.contains(ent.uuid))
        world.entitiesMap += ent.uuid -> ent

    case RemoveEntity(ent) if (world != null && ent != null) =>
      if (world.entitiesMap.contains(ent.uuid))
        world.entitiesMap -= ent.uuid

    case other => // ignore
  }

}

class World {
  // Entity container
  var entitiesMap = Map[UUID,Entity]()
}
```

From time to time, the above code reports:

```
Received unknown message: None
```

Why doesn't the *case None* pattern just above catch it ?

**EDIT**

I found the bug occurs when message *State* comes just before message *AddEntity*, that is, when *entitiesMap* doesn't yet contain the *Entity* refered to by message *State*.

```
01:52 ERROR: [State] Received unknown message: None
uuid: 1b234d30-92ae-11e3-aa12-7071bcb09717
Thread: 152

01:52 ERROR: [State] Received unknown message: None
uuid: 1b234d30-92ae-11e3-aa12-7071bcb09717
Thread: 32

01:52  INFO: [AddEntity] 1b234d30-92ae-11e3-aa12-7071bcb09717: Cube@2f9c3beb
Thread: 152
```

Could this be a threading problem after all ? Within an Actor ?

**EDIT 2**

Following the suggestion of a poster below, I have logged the class names, class loaders reference and class file paths for both *other* and *None*. They're all the same.

**EDIT 3**

*other == None* is *false*

*other.eq(None)* is *false*

*other.equals(None)* is *false*

*other.hashCode* == *None.hashCode*

*System.identityHashCode(other)* != *System.identityHashCode(None)*

Comment: Are you sure your "other" case does not print the same message? ☺

Comment: Do you get compiler warnings like unreachable code?

Comment: Does the "entitiesMap" var change over time? I know it's immutable, but I mean whether you reassign a new immutable map to it.

Comment: I'm sure the second "other" case does not print the same message. I don't get compiler warnings like unreachable code: the code IS reached at runtime. Yes, entitiesMap DOES change over time. I reassign new immutable maps to it but only within the same Actor that receives State message. As I said, it is accessed and updated within a single Akka Actor.

Comment: If I remove the first "case other", sometimes the program crashes saying it can't match scala.None.

Comment: Does it ever happen to match `case None`?

Comment: I don't think I've seen it match `case None`, no. At least not when debugging this issue.

Comment: Could you show how you declare the map in the code snippet? You provided the type but not the code. I suspect some weirdness maybe comes from there.

Comment: Also, please provide the definition of `world`.  Another thing to try: log `other.getClass.getName` and `None.getClass.getName`.  If they both are `scala.None$`, this is really weird.

Comment: Are you importing `None` anywhere in your file?

Comment: I'm not importing `None` in the file.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to provide complete code containing also logic where you're modifying the map?

Comment: After verification, other.getClass.getName and None.getClass.getName are both scala.None$.

Comment: Which scala version? The pattern matcher was rewritten.

Comment: 2.10.1.v20130302-092018-VFINAL-33e32179fd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following advice from everyone telling me this issue was a class loader problem and [printing stack trace at None's construction time](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/IL_RfFj_yxE/AMBGCEhPYpkJ), I've narrowed it down to my useage of Kryo for serializing messages prior to transmitting them over the network.

It seems the default behaviour of Kryo with [singleton objects can lead to my problem exactly](https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/develop/chill-scala/src/main/scala/com/twitter/chill/SingletonSerializer.scala). Kryo is reloading *None* every time it deserializes it, leading to *None*'s *System.identityHashCode* being different.

The problem, then, was [class reloading](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/IL_RfFj_yxE/Wq8bORDwHxQJ), and the solution is to use a library which knows how to handle Scala objects properly for serialization such as [chill-scala](https://github.com/twitter/chill/).

```
package com.twitter.chill

// Singletons are easy, you just return the singleton and don't read:
// It's important you actually do this, or Kryo will generate Nil != Nil, or None != None

class SingletonSerializer[T](obj: T) extends KSerializer[T] {
  def write(kser: Kryo, out: Output, obj: T) {}
  def read(kser: Kryo, in: Input, cls: Class[T]): T = obj
}
```

Comment: I don't remember suggesting class reloading on the linked thread, but looking at it now, it makes me question whether splitting threads over multiple forums is optimal. It could be optimal if it garnered more opinions without losing the thread.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a class loader/class path problem, where `None$` is getting loaded by two class loaders and the two None$.Module$ do not compare equal.

Since the Map is immutable, after you add to it, you've created a new Map.  Suppose the class of new Map is loaded by the alien loader; then when that map returns None, it will return the alien None.

Note that when you add to very small Maps, it uses new to create the next bigger Map; but after a few such allocations, it switches to HashMap.  So it's possible that competing class loaders could change the apparent behavior of the map you get back.

I would print out not only the class names, but the class loader and where the classes are loaded from.

Comment: I was pretty confident this would solve my issue, but I've just confirmed not only is the class name the same: so is the class loader and where the classes are loaded from. For both *other* and *scala.None*.

Comment: I've just tried *other == None* and it returns *false*, so you are unto something, but I couldn't pin point it properly.